# Rails_admin add nested model adding modal in edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, mongoid, rails-admin

I have models: `Client` and `Favourite`. `Client has many Favourites`. I am using rails_admin gem.

In my `Client` model definition I have added this code:

```
rails_admin do

  create do
    exclude_fields :favourites
  end

  update do
  end

end
```

As you can see, I have removed favourites adding form element from my `create`. Now when I open editing page of my selected `Client`, it has this form element:
[image: image1]

I want remove this multi selection form element and leave only modal button for adding `Favourite` in my `Client` and when I click on this button, it must already select current `Client` as attribute of my `Favourite`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I do not like that but :

You can override stylesheets rails_admin...

1 - Identified the parent id like this `#client_ids_field`

2 - Identified the child class of `multi-select` like this `ra-multiselect`

3 - Add `display:block` in your css property `#client_ids_field.ra-multiselect`

[To override rails_admin css](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Theming-and-customization)